# SQL prepared select column using case with column or variable in where

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Is it possible to have a CASE statement work within SELECT which uses a column name or variable from WHERE? Something like

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN lang = french THEN COL1
        WHEN lang = english THEN COL2
        WHEN lang = italian THEN COL3
    END AS language
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    lang = 'english'
```

The important part due to ORM restrictions is that the column name can only be add in the WHERE clause in the format of

```
name = 'value'
```

I have control over the name and value, but the equals operator is not changeable. It is actually a prepared statement, so realistically at one point it becomes

```
...
WHERE
    something = ?
```

But for the purposes of this question, I don't think that is relevant.

I cannot change the fact that this is added in the WHERE clause later but I can change the entire initial MySQL query.

Comment: The "variable" is not from the `where`.  The "variable" appears to be a column.  I'm a bit lost on what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Fair comment, I will clarify

Comment: Is `lang` a column in the table?

Comment: Updated question to reduce confusion

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `lang` is the *variable*, not a column in the data.  If so, the only solution I can think of -- other than dispensing with the application environment which seems to be a big hinderance -- is to unpivot the data and then filter:

```
select tt.col
from ((select 'english' as lang, col1 as col from t) union all
      (select 'french' as lang, col2 from t) union all
      (select 'italian' as lang, col3 from t)
     ) tt
where tt.lang = :lang;
```

Or:

```
select (case when col = 1 then col1
             when col = 2 then col2
             when col = 3 then col3
        end) as col
from t cross join
     (select 'english' as lang, 1 as col union all
      select 'french' as lang, 2 as col union all
      select 'italian' as lang, 3 as col
     ) l
where l.lang = :lang
```